# Linq query on Dictionary<int, double> type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<int, double>` and want to eliminate values equal to a certain value.

At the moment I have

```
Dictionary <int, double> dict = GetDictionary();
dict = dict.Where(x => x.Value != 100).Select(x => x);
```

And am getting the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,double>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,double>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do using Linq?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var newDict = dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Value != 100)
                  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

The reason you are getting a compile error is that Select is an extension on IEnumerable. In the case of a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` you are dealing with an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`